# Cypher query to get all recently updated nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database where all the nodes and relationships have an `updatedAt` property, which is set using `TIMESTAMP()` in a Cypher query. For the sake of argument, let's imagine that all the nodes were last updated *before* 144444444444 and at least one relationship was updated *after* 144444444444.

This cypher query returns no results:

```
WITH 144444444444 AS timestamp
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.updatedAt >= timestamp
WITH n, timestamp
OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[r]->()
WHERE r.updatedAt >= timestamp
RETURN DISTINCT n, r
```

The following query (without the timestamp limitation for `n`) does return the recently updated relationships (which I do want) plus all the nodes (which I don't want):

```
WITH 144444444444 AS timestamp
MATCH (n)
WITH n, timestamp
OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[r]->()
WHERE r.updatedAt >= timestamp
RETURN DISTINCT n, r
```

Suspecting that the `WHERE n.updatedAt >= timestamp` statement might be limiting the possible start and end nodes in the `()-[r]->()` statement, I tried the following:

```
WITH 144444444444 AS timestamp
MATCH (n), (o), (p)
WHERE n.updatedAt >= timestamp
WITH n, o, p, timestamp
OPTIONAL MATCH (o)-[r]->(p)
WHERE r.updatedAt >= timestamp
RETURN DISTINCT n, r
```

Here, I explicitly allow the start node to be any node at all. However, once again, I do not get the recently updated relationships.

What query can I use to get all the nodes and all the relationships that have been updated since a given timestamp, and none of those that were updated before that time?

---

EDIT: The following query, using an optional match for `n`, appears to work:

```
WITH 144444444444 AS timestamp
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)
WHERE n.updatedAt >= timestamp
WITH n, timestamp
OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[r]->()
WHERE r.updatedAt >= timestamp
RETURN DISTINCT n, r
```

So my question becomes: why does the query which uses `WITH n, o, p, timestamp` fail to return the recent relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

It looks like you do not have any **nodes** with an `updatedAt` value that is >= 144444444444.

That would explain why the `MATCH (n) WHERE n.timestamp >= timestamp` queries do not work, but the `OPTIONAL MATCH` variant does.

A `MATCH` clause that fails to find a match will cause the entire query to abort and not return any results. But an `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause always allows the query to proceed.

If I am correct, then this query won't return any rows.

```
WITH 144444444444 AS timestamp
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.updatedAt >= timestamp
RETURN n;
```

Comment: `n.timestamp >= timestamp` was a copy and paste error that I have now corrected.

Comment: "A `MATCH` clause that fails to find a match will cause the entire query [to] abort" ... so in my third query, `(o)` and `(p)` never get the chance to do anything. Thanks for the insight.